# Please undelete and preserve 'How do you edit the name of a bookmark? (MS Word 2013)'?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Would you please undelete [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/943117/how-do-you-edit-the-name-of-a-bookmark-ms-word-2013), which constitutes a common problem? I would be grateful for two upvotes, simply to protect the question from automatic deletion. Thank you.

Here it is quoted—as well as a screenshot below—for users with less than 10,000 rep so they can review this:

> #### How do you edit the name of a bookmark? (MS Word 2013)
>
> I found no answer to the question above
>   [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-delete-bookmarks-d13f4bab-fb76-4e09-9c3a-239e1a0c1568#__toc279738337),
>   or on
>   [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ms+word+edit+bookmark&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#tbs=qdr:y&q=ms+word+edit+bookmark+name).

[image]

Comment: <10K users can't see the deleted question.  Can you post a copy here or describe the question and why it was closed/deleted?

Comment: That's a pretty poor quality question right there. No chance at all for any information outside of links?

Comment: You have multiple 1k+ rep accounts, you obviously understand how StackExchange works. As such, I'm sure you can see why this was a poorly asked question. I would suggest expanding the question here to show the mods you can ask good question and that this deserves to be reopened.

Comment: While the title does sum up the question pretty well it should not be the only information on your problem. You should summarise the steps to recreate your problem for those that do not know how to use the bookmarking features in Word. You should also put any useful information you have *in your question*.

Comment: Searching for "microsoft word edit bookmark name" gives the answer as the first result returned, so "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @LePressentiment - I see no reason to salvage that question.  It would only continue to receive additional downvotes and likely result in your inability to ask new questions in future.  Besides the answer to your question is contained in the Word's help documentation

Comment: @DavidPostill To which link do you refer?

Comment: @Ramhound `Besides the answer to your question is contained in the Word's help documentation` : Where?

Comment: @LePressentiment Did you even do the search I suggested? The first link is [Bookmarks - Changing name of existing bookmark](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=57050)

Comment: @DavidPostill I suspected that as your referent, but wasn't sure. Please see my updated OP.

Comment: @DavidPostill I checked that post out as well. It's almost 10 years old, and doesn't actually answer the question. The only suggestion there is to delete and re-add the bookmark. Playing the devil's advocate here, but did *you* even read that result?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yes, of course I read it. It's a workaround for the problem ... do you have a better answer?

Comment: I don't. And perhaps that's the answer? There is no way to edit bookmarks, you have to delete and remake them.

Comment: @MichaelFrank [Change the “name” of a bookmark not the text of it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/579fdfc1-0e57-419e-b4d0-e01bdc40c8cc/change-the-name-of-a-bookmark-not-the-text-of-it?forum=worddev) - "There isn't a rename function. You have to delete the old name and mark the range with a new bookmark name. Here's sample VBA code: ..." - yet another workaround.

Comment: Duplicate [su] question [Batch rename multiple bookmarks in Word .docx file](http://superuser.com/q/359066)

Comment: @LePressentiment What you want to do is not possible (in one step). [Change the “name” of a bookmark not the text of it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/579fdfc1-0e57-419e-b4d0-e01bdc40c8cc/change-the-name-of-a-bookmark-not-the-text-of-it?forum=worddev) - "There isn't a rename function. You have to delete the old name and mark the range with a new bookmark name. Here's sample VBA code: ..." - yet another workaround. And see

Comment: @DavidPostill Workaround != Answer. I'm not saying the workarounds are incorrect, only that the answer should be "There is no way to edit the name directly. But you can do *this* or *that* to achieve the same result." Concise and direct is best. :)

Comment: @MichaelFrank Exactly how I was planning to answer....

Comment: @LePressentiment See the new question by Mokubai [Renaming a bookmark in Word 2010](http://superuser.com/q/967036). I've answered it. There is also an add-in which might do what you want. Please take a look.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe.

But consider why it was deleted. There's close to zero effort on actually writing the question. If those two links go down, we'll never *ever* know what didn't work. Links should *supplement* a question, not be the question.

How would I get this undeleted?

Edit the question (least I think you can. Else let us know and we'll work out something).

Tell us the story of your problem. What are you trying to do? What is the expected behaviour. What have you tried so far and so on. (I personally use [this checklist](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) on ESR's excellent how to ask questions the smart way when I ask questions here or SR).

I believe you can custom flag it afterwards, and link back to this question in case another mod handles it.

In short, earn your undeletion and your upvotes will handle themselves.

As is though, its not a great question and I am not inclined to think it should be undeleted.

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph: I've edited my post, but I do not know what from those 2 links, because they discuss nothing about the problem.

Comment: @LePressentiment - So why did you include them in your question, if they have nothing to do with your problem, just not compute.

Comment: @Ramhound To prove the lack of information?

Comment: @LePressentiment - So you posted irrelevant links in your question, to prove there is no information, but end up not actually in words asking a question ( a question title does not count )?

Comment: @Ramhound I quoted that link following http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9680/please-undelete-and-preserve-how-do-you-edit-the-name-of-a-bookmark-ms-word-2/9682?noredirect=1#comment26405_9680.

Comment: "I found no answer to the question above [here]" (Link points to picture of cat eating spaghetti). <-- Proof there's a lack of information about bookmarks. ;)